# Formula field in Databand of Fast-report

Tags: formula, fastreport

I'm Using Fast-report as the reporting tool in my latest project, where I'm new to this tool. Now I'm finding an issue while trying to do a multiplication in the data-band of fast-report like `[SampleData1.Qty]*[SampleData1.Unit_Price]`.

My data source is SQL Server and passing the data to the On the render the Report throws an exception,

Can I know how to do operations on the Text?

Regards
Raghu

Comment: Use `[SampleData1.Qty*SampleData1.Unit_Price]` in the `Text` object.

Answer (score 0):

Add scope with `[]`:

```
[[SampleData1.Qty]*[SampleData1.Unit_Price]]
```